# Identify 'Career' Participants on StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow, jobs, flair

Has it been considered to allow some form of optional (opt-in) piece of flair (in this context, just an icon next to your contributions) on stackoverflow indicating you have your CV online with "Careers," and you are interested in job-offers. Perhaps this is already in the works, but just in case it isn't I thought I'd put it out there as a suggestion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> indicating you have your CV online with "Careers," and you are interested in job-offers.

I'm not sure that is a great idea:

- it removes much of the need for employers to go to the trouble of, you know, *paying*
- it says "hey, current employer! I'm going as soon as I can find something I hate less"

I **really** don't think that this is a good idea. Fine for contractors, maybe.

Answer (score 6):

I sure don't want any **more flair cluttering up the Q&A pages**. So, I'm against it for that reason.

I don't want to give any more justification to **authors who feel slighted** when someone edits their post and crowds their flair. So, against it for *that* reason.

[As Marc points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25352/identify-career-paticipants-on-stackoverflow/25359#25359), it kinda **defeats the whole privacy aspect** of SOC. Sure, you could limit the visibility to signed in employers, but... what's the point? They could just use SOC! So, against it for that reason as well.

And if all that weren't enough, it **smacks of desperation**. "I've hit bottom and am left with no option but to spam SO with answers in hope that someone will notice me" desperation. That *can't* be good...

---

If you really feel good about your CV and want to show it off, just... mention it in your "about me" box. Heck, you could do that now and maybe save the $29... ;-)

Comment: "no option but to spam SO with answers" - are you on about me again? <g>

Comment: If the shoe fits... (j/k) :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this, just add a link to your public CV in the "About Me" part of your SO profile.

Comment: what is the "checkbox in the SO profile" for?

Answer (score 1):

I could see having this icon available only to logged in employers when they are viewing SO, but I don't think it should display to others.  For employers it would be very handy identifying individuals -- perhaps it could also be linked to the person's CV.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a checkbox in the profile. Perhaps if it's checked, then you have a link to the public profile of careers when it's available.

Comment: Yeah; I remember that, but I was more interested in the implementation.

Comment: Perhaps just a star below your avatar linking to your CSO CV?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this was declined, but I think the SO folks are missing a very important point:

It helps to have some motivation for people to answer questions, over-and-above "wanting to help people" and trying to earn points.

Also, I think the issue of public exposure, clutter, etc, could be mitigated or eliminated by allowing users to control when the icon was visible.