# Mark posts on Stack Overflow for people with filed CVs on Careers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**

Comment: Your profile is the right place to put this. If the employer is too dumb to get that, you do not want to work for him.

Comment: Why not just change your DisplayName to something like **Hire Me - RickNZ?**

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25352/identify-career-participants-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this would add relevant information to Stack Overflow as a site. SO is a site for answering and finding the answers to programming related questions. Whether the asker or answerer is currently searching for a job has no relevance, and should not be displayed in any way with the their information on the question page. Any person can choose to add a link to the public CV to their profile, because your SO profile is your sandbox to put out there any additional information you want people to have. Furthermore, I'm not convinced employers would or do search SO for people to hire, I would expect they will use careers, which has a search system tailored to helping them find the potential employees they might want to hire.

Comment: SO is also about reputation. I often go to profile pages to find out a little about the people who ask and answer questions. If they link to a resume, I tend to visit that too. SO rep can't tell you anything about someones real world life experience in the way that a CV will. -Especially if they're new to SO. I can't see the harm in a badge that tells me that a person is proud enough of their work history to have created a public CV.

Comment: So long as it is contained to the user's profile, I wouldn't be upset about an "official" way that links to your public CV if you have one. Since the point of the profile is to gain more information about that user. But I wouldn't want to see anything on the question page that only shows if you have a public CV.

Answer (score 3):

Linking to the profile could make it discoverable by search engines.  That's intentionally not the case so you can keep your "public" CV from being found accidentally by someone you don't want to know about it -- such as a recruiter.   I do have my CV linked in my profile, though I've added a disclaimer requesting no recruiters use it to market me -- at least without my consent.